# setting focus on parent of listview layout

Tags: android

I stocked in a problem. I have a listView and this listView is just for showing data row by row and items are all disabled using override function isEnabled to false.
so this is my code:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/baseLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I need to set click listener on baseLayout but every thing I've done not made the focus on baseLayout and listview calls absListView touch listener. any idea?
    ...

Answer (score 1):

You have to set listener on list cell, such as. 
It is example for recyler view, but it is same case on listview.

class SearchListAdapter(private val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
private var products: List<Repo> = arrayListOf()
var listener: AdapterListener? = null

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, i: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_repo, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return products.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.bind(position, products[position])
}

fun setList(contacts: List<Repo>) {
    this.products = contacts
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : BindingViewHolder<ItemRepoBinding>(itemView) {
    fun bind(pos: Int, contact: Repo) {
        if (binding == null) {
            return
        }

        binding.tvTitle.text = contact.name
        binding.setVariable(
            BR.tintlist,
            context.resources.getColorStateList(R.color.xml_color_btn_title)
        )

        binding.root.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener?.onClick(pos, contact)
            }
        })
    }
}

interface AdapterListener {
    fun onClick(position: Int, info: Repo)
}
```

}

Comment: I know that but i want to make listView focus and click being disabled and then call clicklistener for parent view. any idea for this? @khaan-koca